# Open Source Virtualization Solution

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I'm looking for an open source solution to launch, manage **and interact** with VMs (10-15 VMs, Linux and mostly Windows Servers) through a web interface. I bumped into [archipel](http://archipelproject.org/) , [karessansui](http://karesansui-project.info/) , oVirt, Virtualbox/phpvirtualbox, Xen, KVM ... and, I'm really confused.

Ideally, the solution needs to be easy to install (an all in one iso containing the hypervisor may be?) and to use.

Recommendations?

Comment: VirtualBox is quite easy to set up and use, and has a user-made [web interface](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/) although virtulisation is quite an advanced concept for most. It's probably not best to ask "which should I use" more "how can I install x".

Comment: I don't mean to sound silly, but, why does it have to be open source? Why not just go for a proven technology such as Hyper-V server or ESXI, which are both free and get a web interface for them (there are a few that are free)... After all, if you are not going to look at the code any way (I am guessing), why not just get a solid solution... In the long run, if you are attempting to run VMs, it will do the job just as well!

Comment: @tombull89 but you can't interact with VMs using virtualbox's web interface

Answer (score 1):

You might want to decide for the Hypervisor, i.e. the virtualization backend technology first and then decide for a web based management solution. Picking the hypervisor primary on its interface is not recommended in my opinion. We use [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/) for virtualization, which i can recommend, especially for linux guests. If you want to manage KVM VMs through a web interface there are multiple options, one of them you named already, [oVirt](http://ovirt.org/about.html), which is based on [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/). If I remember correctly, libvirt can also manage XEN VMs, but i'm not sure if those are also supported by oVirt. An alternative is [Proxmox VE](http://pve.proxmox.com/), which can manage KVM and [openVZ](http://wiki.openvz.org/) guests and does not depend on libvirt.

Comment: Does any of the available web interfaces show the virtual machine running in a new window/tab? The thing is, I've tested virtualbox/phpvirtualbox and the web interface just starts the VMs.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean. proxmox contains a java applet VNC viewer, so you can actually interact with the virtual machine from your browser if thats what you mean.